# Is there a way to limit my executable's ability to delete to only files it has created?

Tags: windows, file, file-permissions

I'm on Windows writing a C++ executable that deletes and replaces some files in a directory it creates during an earlier run session.  Maybe I'm a little panicky, but since my directory and file arguments for the deletions are generated by parsing an input file's path, I worry about the parse throwing out a much higher or different directory due to an oversight and systematically deleting unrelated files unintentionally.

Is there a way to limit my executable's reign to only include write/delete access to files it has created during earlier run sessions, while retaining read access to everything else?  Or at least provide a little extra peace of mind that, even if I really mis-speak my strings to `DeleteFileA()` and `RemoveDirectoryA()` I'll avoid causing catastrophic damage?

It doesn't need to be a restriction to the entire executable, it's good enough if it limits the function calls to delete and remove in some way.

Comment: You might add created files' pathnames to a global array of strings, then check if the path is contained within that array whenever you're about to call `DeleteFileA()` or `RemoveDirectoryA()`. If the program needs to keep memory of files created and deleted in previous executions, you might save those paths in a separate file and load them in memory everytime the program starts. If you need something more intrinsic, I have no clue.

Comment: You might be able to do something by creating a user specific to your executable, and controlling the permissions of that user to only be able to delete files it owns (that it created earlier).

Comment: @Nastor  - these both seem good, it doesn't need to be intrinsic or have any standard of care, I'm the only one I can hit with the hammers I'm throwing in the air